# Custom product limit value change if i change category

Tags: magento2, category-products

If a user set custom value for "Product per page" (eg: ?product_list_limit=48) the value is restore to default (admin value) if user change category. Why? In magento 1 the user custom value was maintained for all categories

Comment: what you have done for this, kindly share code.

Comment: no customizations, it seem to be default behavior